# Get data from JQuery and store it in PHP Variable

Tags: php, jquery, html5-canvas

Here's my code:

```
html2canvas([document.getElementById('myCanvas')], 
    {
      onrendered: function(canvas) 
         {
           $.post('save.php', 
            {
              data: canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg')
            }, 

            function (file) 
            {
             window.location.href =  'download.php?path='+ file
             });
          }
     });
```

When I execute it using PHP `$_POST['data']`; , it gives me an error: Undefined index: data
How do I get the data and store it in a PHP variable? Thanks!

Comment: `print_r($_POST);` see what is result?

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
html2canvas([document.getElementById('myCanvas')], 
      {
        onrendered: function(canvas) 
        {
          $.post('save.php', 
          {
            data: {
                "Param1":canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg')
                }
          }, 

          function (file) 
          {
            window.location.href =  'download.php?path='+ file
          });
        }
      });
```

And in your PHP functions get the variable using

```
$_POST['Param1']
```

Comment: it does not produce any error but the conversion to image/jpeg doesn't work :(